# Regulate access to resources like DB and filesystem

Tags: c#, database, architecture

I'm facing the following situation:

A system I'm working on has a few different parts(services and ASP.net) with seperate responsibilities. These parts are combined by 2 resources: A MSSQL-DB and files on a windows filesystem.

Currently all these parts access these resources individually. I think this is causing unpredictability and inconsistency.

I'm thinking of introducing a service that regulates access to these resources. I'm not sure if this is an accepted design principle.

The general question is:

What kind of solution should I be looking at and what should I keep in mind when designing this?

Specific questions:

- Is this just a Data Access Layer?
- Is it bad to introduce a SPOF like this?
- Can you recommend any reading material aimed at this kind of solution? (especially if there's specific material for C#)

edit because of a great question by allen-smithee:

The database is currently accessed by embedded queries. They are seperated into a class but these are different for every service so it's not a shared library.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "unpredictability and inconsistency"? Is the system experiencing actual data inconsistency issues and race conditions? How do your services currently access the DB - embedded SQL queries, ORM or stored procs?

Comment: @allen-smithee Thanks, these are great questions. Yes, inconsistency in DB and racing conditions are an issue. Deadlocks are plenty. Currently they are using embedded SQL queries. I rather not use stored procs to solve this problem. I like to keep my queries managed in the main respository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ A Data Access Layer simply encapsulates the data logic, what you need is [concurrency control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control) to ensure consistency of your data model across the independent services.

2/ Depending how you implement concurrency it can be a single point of failure but I don't think there is anything wrong with that - "plan for failure" is a great design mantra. You can build in redundancy and fail-over mechanisms, or you can distribute your concurrency control across your services.

3/ The way you choose to implement concurrency will depend on how your application functions and what your users expect. To give some specific scenarios:

#### Scenario A

When a service begins an update start a transaction and take out one or more row-level locks for the records involved. If any other service tries to edit the record at the same time either block or return an error such as 'this record is currently locked'. Note that all locks have to be taken before reading and kept for the duration of the update to ensure consistency with other writes.

Pros - Fairly straight forward to implement for small data models. MSSQL supports plenty of locking scenarios and even custom [application locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) that you can use to group resources.

Cons - If your transaction needs to access multiple tables/rows and different services or functions access overlapping tables you can easily get into all sorts of deadlock problems.
MSSQL generally prefers pessimistic locking and can escalate locks from row to page and table level, which means read and write locks may behave in ways you wouldn't initially expect. You may need to spend a considerable amount of time debugging these interactions in SQL Server Profiler and be prepared to make changes to your data model to work around these issues.

#### Scenario B

Each table row has an incremental version number. A service reads the data it needs, performs a series of updates, and then within a transaction lock checks the current row version against the one it used for the update. If the version numbers do not match it rolls back the transaction, cancelling the update. The service may then attempt to perform the operation again starting with reading the data.

Pros - Readers are not blocked and the lock is held only very briefly while the service tries to commit the update. MSSQL has built-in support for this concurrency method in the form of 'Row Versioning' with the 'Snapshot Isolation' level. If conflicts are rare this method can be extremely responsive - perfect for real-time applications.

Cons - This method may require significant changes to your data model and the service behaviour.

#### Scenario C

A single data service is responsible for all data access. Other services request data from and submit updates to this service. The service is responsible for reading and writing to the database and filesystem, and performs some level of data integrity checking and resolves data conflicts.

Pros - Encapsulates data integrity and control in one module, simplifying other services. Allows you to implement caching, locking etc at the application level providing finer-grained control.

Cons - Significant changes to existing architecture required. Resolving data conflicts can require a significant amount of code if you choose to resolve at the field level. Services will need to be able to handle a rejected update when resolution is not possible.

---

That's the major scenarios I can think of off the top of my head but there are plenty more. Generally all concurrency control for data will revolve around locking while performing an action (pessimistic locking); performing an action and then checking for a conflict (optimistic locking via versioning); or performing an action and then merging conflicts (conflict resolution.)

Thinking about your specific data model and how the model is updated will guide which mix of these techniques you will use. Searching for any of the terms above will give you plenty to read and there are a lot of Technet articles that specifically address these issues in an MSSQL context. Take heart - I've seen good programmers get this stuff wrong, it really is a challenging problem, but it is solvable if you work through it methodically.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer. I'm probably going to try scenario C since I also want to be able to manage the logic from one place(there are exact copies of complicated functions throughout different services right now). This would also increase scalability and manageability. I will search for some best practices around this solution.